# Where does the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ come from in the force equation $\vec{F}=\frac{1}{2}Q\vec{E}$?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

Generally, I have seen equations like $\vec{F}=Q\vec{E}$  which obviously makes sense. However, in the case of a capacitor where the force experienced by each of the plates (having charges $\pm Q$ and the electric field between the plates is constant which equals $\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon}$) of a parallel plate capacitor, a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is introduced to the above equation. Can anyone explain why this is true? It'd be much better if you explained intuitively (or using fewer formulae).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and it often catches people out.

Here is the answer. When a charge $q$ is subject to a field $\bf E_{\rm other}$ it experiences a force
$$
{\bf f} = q {\bf E}_{\rm other}
$$
The subscript 'other' here is there to remind us that the field experienced by the charge in this equation is the field at the location of charge *owing to all the other charges in the universe*. It does *not* include the field owing to the charge $q$ itself.

In the case of a capacitor you have plates 1 and 2 carrying charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. The total electric field between the plates is
$$
{\bf E}_{\rm tot} = {\bf E}_1 + {\bf E_2}
$$
where ${\bf E}_1$ is caused by $Q_1$ and ${\bf E}_2$ is caused by $Q_2$. The force on plate 1 is $Q_1 E_2$. The force on plate 2 is $Q_2 E_1$. And $E_1 = E_2 = E_{\rm tot}/2$.

That's one way to set out the reasoning, but it is subtle because at each plate you have $E_{\rm tot} = \sigma / \epsilon$ where $\sigma$ is the local surface charge density. So
$$
E_{\rm tot} = \frac{Q_1}{\epsilon_0 A} = \frac{Q_2}{\epsilon_0 A}
$$
where $A$ is the area of the plates (assumed flat). This makes it look as if each of $Q_1$ or $Q_2$ on its own is somehow causing the whole field, which is not true. What you have to realise is that this equation for $E_{\rm tot}$ gives the field between the plates, outside the conducting surfaces. Inside the conductor the field is zero. So in fact the field falls from $E_{\rm tot}$ to zero along a line passing into either plate, so the average field experienced by the charge on either plate is indeed half of $E_{\rm tot}$ in this configuration.